# How to change all images by one click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View, Image, Text } from "react-native";

const n1 = require("../img/n1.png");
const n2 = require("../img/n2.png");
const n3 = require("../img/n3.png");
const n4 = require("../img/n4.png");
const n5 = require("../img/n5.png");

const n0 = require("../img/n0.png");

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, image: n1, title: " n1 " },
        { id: 2, image: n2, title: " n2 " },
        { id: 3, image: n3, title: " n3" },
        { id: 4, image: n4, title: " n4 " },
        { id: 5, image: n5, title: " n5" },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.box}>
              <View style={styles.info}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title} </Text>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  info: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  image: {
    width: 173,
    height: 88,
  },
  title: {
    color: "#707070",
    opacity: 1,
  },
  box: {
    marginLeft: -120,
    marginTop: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

This is part of the code that I have deleted some code not relevant to this question.

My question is how do I change all images(n1-n5) by one click to n0.

The page will show 5 different images(n1-n5) in a list, then after clicking a button, all images will be replaced by n0.

I got some idea about setState, but I am new to React and don't know how to make it work(or not state) even after search.

BTW, its a webpage, but I use react-native-web to get the images more pretty arranged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple `map` operation.

```
handleClick = () =>
  this.setState((prev) => ({
    data: prev.data.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      image: n0,
      title: "n0",
    })),
  }));
```

Comment: thank you, it is a very simple and neat solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding extraData to the flat list to re render when button clicked

```
<FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={this.state.data}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.box}>
              <View style={styles.info}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title} </Text>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: item.image }} />
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />

....
//add function for button click:
onButtonClicked(){
//create the new data array
//replace it with the old array state
this.setState({data: new_data}); //flat list should re render when state changed
}
```